# Quelle est la logique du dernier "que" dans "Qu'est-ce que l'amour ?" ?

Tags: syntaxe

"Qu'est-ce, l'amour ?" - je pourrais comprendre cette phrase logiquement. *What is it, love?*

"Qu'est-ce que c'est, l'amour ?" - celle-ci également. *What is it that it is, love?*

Mais que signifie et que fait le dernier "que" dans "Qu'est-ce que l'amour ?" - je ne comprends pas. Est-ce que ceci veut dire "what" ? Est-ce "only" ? Est-ce "that" ? Les francophones comprendent-ils cette construction logiquement ?

Comment: Ce deuxième « que »  n'est  pas *what* à lui tout seul. Ne veut pas non plus dire « seulement ».  « Qu'est-ce que X ? » est la forme soutenue (littéraire) de « qu'est-ce que c'est que X  ? ». Grammaticalement ce « que »  pourrait être un pronom relatif, et il serait attribut, mais ce n'est de ma part qu'une supposition. La tournure « qu'est ce que » est un gallicisme et il ne faut pas lui chercher d'équivalent dans une autre langue. En anglais « qu'est ce que » (la tournure complète donc), c'est *what*.  (Qu'est ce que tu fais ? → *What are you doing* ?

Comment: @None C'est une bonne réponse, plutôt qu'un commentaire?

Comment: @Frank Je n'ai aucune référence valide pour appuyer *que*  attribut, d'où le conditionnel. Faut que laisse ça murir.

Comment: Peux-tu donner le contexte dans lequel tu as rencontré les deux premières phrases parce que je suis gêné par la ponctuation que tu donnes. J'aurais écrit « Qu'est-ce l'amour ? » (*What is love?*) mais avec un signe de ponctuation (que je verrais plutôt comme un point d'interrogation)  « Qu'est-ce ? de l'amour ? » (*What is it? love ?*).

Comment: @None Je ne les ai rencontré que dans ma tête. Je voulais exprimer que ces phrases auraient du sens logique pour moi.

Comment: @None Bizarre, pour moi, *Qu'est-ce, l'amour ?* passe beaucoup mieux que la même phrase sans virgule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je soupçonne que la majorité des francophones ne détaillent pas tous les mots dans le gallicisme *est-ce que*. Pour les francophones *est-ce que* est une locution qui sert à poser des questions directes sans faire l'inversion du sujet. (« Que vois-tu ? » « Qu'*est-ce que* que tu vois ? », veulent dire exactement la même chose, la première phrase étant d'un niveau de langue plus soutenu, surtout à l'oral). La tournure « est-ce que » est un gallicisme, c'est à dire spécifique au français et il ne faut pas lui chercher d'équivalent dans une autre langue. Vouloir traduire cette locution mot à mot en anglais serait aussi incongru que de vouloir faire correspondre le *do* (*did*) anglais à un mot en particulier dans la traduction en français d'une question en anglais (« Qu'est-ce que tu as vu ? » → *What did you see*?)

Dans le *Bon usage*<sup>1</sup>, Grevisse écrit que :

> *Que*, relatif, peut-être attribut neutre.
> (...)
> On peut considérer qu'on a le même *que* attribut neutre (dont la fonction n'est plus sentie, parce que ces expressions sont figées) dans ***Qu'est-ce* QUE..?**<sup>2</sup>  et dans : *Si j'étais* QUE *de vous ; ce que c'est* que *de nous !* (...) — De même encore dans  : *C'est une belle fleur* QUE l*a rose* [qui s'analyserait, selon Nyrop<sup>3</sup> : *c'est une belle fleur* (ce) *que* (est) *la rose*] ou dans : *C'est horrible* QUE de *haïr.*  — Mais on peut aussi, avec plus d'un grammairien, (...) estimer que dans *c'est une belle fleur* QUE *la rose* ; — *C'est horrible* QUE *de haïr* ; — *si j'étais* que *de vous* ;  [...] le *que* est une conjonction. — Pour Frei<sup>4</sup> dans *c'est une belle fleur que la rose*, il n'y a pas lieu de supposer une ellipse du verbe *être*, et que le *que* est un séparatif (sorte de pause prononcée), simple signe d'inversion. (...)

Dans une édition ultérieure (1993), que je n'ai pas sous la main mais qui est citée dans l'article que je mets [en lien](http://w3.erss.univ-tlse2.fr/publications/CarnetsGrammaire/carnGram11.pdf) :

> Grevisse  [analyse toujours la construction *c'est une belle fleur que la rose*] comme attribut mais « de toute façon, ces expressions sont figées, et le locuteur y sentirait plutôt la conjonction *que* ».

Relatif  ? Conjonction ? Ces quelques extraits montrent que l'analyse de ce QUE est loin d'être évidente pour la majorité des locuteurs natifs. Pour approfondir le sujet on pourra se référer à la lecture de l'article cité ci-dessus<sup>5</sup>.

---

<sub>Je ne réponds pas à la question « Est-ce "only" ? Est-ce "that" ? », *que* à lui tout seul ne veut pas dire *only*, et *that* pouvant avoir plusieurs fonctions grammaticales différentes la comparaison avec l'anglais ne me semble pas pertinente.</sub>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Le bon usage*, §547, dixième édition, 1975.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>  
<sup><sup>3</sup> [Nyrop](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kristoffer_Nyrop), *Grammaire historique de la langue française*</sup>.
<sup><sup>4</sup> [Frei](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Frei), *Grammaire des fautes*.</sup>
<sup><sup>5</sup> [*Les constructions liées : “c'est une saine occupation que l'horticulture”, Étude synchronique et diachronique*](http://w3.erss.univ-tlse2.fr/publications/CarnetsGrammaire/carnGram11.pdf), Magali Rouquier, 2003. In « Carnets de grammaire », Rapports internes de l'ERSS.</sup>

Comment: Très intéressant ! Je penche aussi pour l'explication du *que* séparatif qui lie les deux parties de la phrase davantage qu'un "qu'est-ce, l'amour ?" à la cassure un peu brutale.